# Failure Text Response in Jmeter

Tags: текст, jmeter, response

Подскажите, пожалуйста, какойт ответ должен быть от Text response если в запросе ошибка? В Jmeter. Спасибо

Answer (score 0):

[Может быть какой угодно](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7231#section-6.5):

> The 4xx (Client Error) class of status code indicates that the client
> seems to have erred.  Except when responding to a HEAD request, the
> server SHOULD send a representation containing an explanation of the
> error situation, and whether it is a temporary or permanent
> condition.  These status codes are applicable to any request method.
> User agents SHOULD display any included representation to the user.

РЕКОМЕНДУЕТСЯ предоставить информацию о причине ошибки и как ее можно исправить. Вот статус код и сообщение ОБЯЗАНЫ соответствовать допущенной клиентом ошибке.

Если вам нужно проверить код, сообщение и текст ответа - можете воспользоваться [Response Assertion](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/response-assertions-in-jmeter)

Comment: Да. я как раз Response Assertion и использую. Так вот мне нужно понять, что система должна ответить в Text Response, если я например введу вместо GET GOT(невалидный)

Comment: если систему писали нормальные люди - ответит [HTTP 501](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/501), а если русские - возможны варианты

Comment: В результате писали нормальные люди :)  Большое вам спасибо, спасли!!!